# How to group events that happened close in time

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, time-series, lubridate

I want to group – by assigning a "group ID" – rows of data for events that happened *in temporal proximity* to each other.

For example, consider having a log of events from a computer, and you want to group together events that happened close to each other.

```r
tibble::tribble(
  ~event_id,          ~happened_at,
      "xyz", "2023-07-31 13:35:06",
      "tsv", "2023-07-31 13:35:07",
      "abc", "2023-07-31 13:41:30",
      "fgh", "2023-07-31 13:42:05",
      "dda", "2023-07-31 13:42:12",
      "ggf",  "2023-08-01 4:43:15",
      "oor", "2023-08-01 13:49:36",
      "wqe", "2023-08-01 14:33:10",
      "oop", "2023-08-01 14:34:14"
  )
```

I want to add another column that accounts for groups of events, such that if 2 or more events happened within several seconds, they should get the same "group ID". Otherwise, single events would get a group ID of their own.

```r
# desired output
tibble::tribble(
  ~event_id,          ~happened_at, ~group_id,
      "xyz", "2023-07-31 13:35:06",        1,
      "tsv", "2023-07-31 13:35:07",        1,
      "abc", "2023-07-31 13:41:30",        2,
      "fgh", "2023-07-31 13:42:05",        2,
      "dda", "2023-07-31 13:42:12",        2,
      "ggf",  "2023-08-01 4:43:15",        3,
      "oor", "2023-08-01 13:49:36",        4,
      "wqe", "2023-08-01 14:33:10",        5,
      "oop", "2023-08-01 14:34:14",        5
  )
```

While this seems like a basic problem, I cannot think of a way to do it. Any idea or "best practice" on such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the *proximity* first. For demonstration purposes, I have defined it as 2 mins but you can chose it based on your dataset.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

cutoff_secs <- 120L 

df %>%
  mutate(happened_at = ymd_hms(happened_at)) %>%
  arrange(happened_at) %>%
  mutate(group_id = cumsum(as.integer(difftime(happened_at, 
                           lag(happened_at, default = first(happened_at)), 
                           units = "secs")) > cutoff_secs) + 1)

#  event_id happened_at         group_id
#  <chr>    <dttm>                 <dbl>
#1 xyz      2023-07-31 13:35:06        1
#2 tsv      2023-07-31 13:35:07        1
#3 abc      2023-07-31 13:41:30        2
#4 fgh      2023-07-31 13:42:05        2
#5 dda      2023-07-31 13:42:12        2
#6 ggf      2023-08-01 04:43:15        3
#7 oor      2023-08-01 13:49:36        4
#8 wqe      2023-08-01 14:33:10        5
#9 oop      2023-08-01 14:34:14        5
```

In `difftime` we calculate the difference between the consecutive values of `happened_at` and if they exceed `cutoff_secs` increment the count of `group_id`.